# Symfony2 Security problem

Tags: security, authentication, symfony

i'm going to adapt my web project (based on symfony2 PR5) to symfony2 PR7. Everything is pretty clear with this migration except the Security bundle. Here is my security configuration:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Application\PermissionsBundle\Entity\Stuff: sha1
    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: PermissionsBundle:Stuff, property: username}
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: .*
            form_login:
                check_path:   /login-check-admin
                login_path:   /login-admin
                failure_path: /login-admin
            logout:     true
            anonymous: true 
        backend:
            pattern: /admin.*
            form_login:
                check_path: /login-check-admin
                login_path: /login-admin
            logout: true
            security: true
            anonymous: false
    access_control:
        - { path: /admin.*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Routing configuration:

```
_security_login:
    pattern: /login-admin
    defaults: { _controller: PermissionsBundle:Security:login }

_security_check:
    pattern: /login-check-admin

_security_logout:
    pattern: /logout-admin

_security_status:
    pattern: /sec_status
    defaults: { _controller: PermissionsBundle:Security:status }

_security_get_username:
    pattern: /security/get/username
    defaults: { _controller: PermissionsBundle:Security:getUserName }
```

When I try to authenticate, I get a 404 fpr login checking:
Firebug output: http://impic.ru/uploads/2011/2303/53849205_61601933.jpeg

Can anybody please help me with this problem? This code works fine in PR5, but not in PR7. Official symfony documentation hasn't changed yet. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I've got exaclly the same problem  and I've no idea how to solve it :(.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. You cannot customize logout and login_check routing patterns. It means that your security.yml file should looks like this:

```
form_login:
    check_path:   /login_check
    login_path:   /login
```

and your routing.yml file should looks like this:

```
_security_check:
    pattern: /login_check
_security_logout:
    pattern: /logout
```

These work perfect for me.